# Java - Insert a single row at a time into google Big Query ?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am creating an application where every time a user clicks on an article, I need to capture the article data and the user data to calculate the reach of every article and be able to run analytics on the reached data.

My application is on App Engine.

When I check documentation for inserts into BQ, most of them point towards bulk inserts in the form of Jobs or Streams.

**Question**:
Is it even a good practice to insert into big Query one row at a time every time a user action is initiated ? If so, could you point me to some Java code to effectively do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are limits on the number of load jobs and DML queries (1,000 per day), so you'll need to use [streaming inserts](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery) for this kind of application. Note that streaming inserts are different from loading data from a Java stream.

```
TableId tableId = TableId.of(datasetName, tableName);
// Values of the row to insert
Map<String, Object> rowContent = new HashMap<>();
rowContent.put("booleanField", true);
// Bytes are passed in base64
rowContent.put("bytesField", "Cg0NDg0="); // 0xA, 0xD, 0xD, 0xE, 0xD in base64
// Records are passed as a map
Map<String, Object> recordsContent = new HashMap<>();
recordsContent.put("stringField", "Hello, World!");
rowContent.put("recordField", recordsContent);
InsertAllResponse response =
    bigquery.insertAll(
        InsertAllRequest.newBuilder(tableId)
            .addRow("rowId", rowContent)
            // More rows can be added in the same RPC by invoking .addRow() on the builder
            .build());
if (response.hasErrors()) {
  // If any of the insertions failed, this lets you inspect the errors
  for (Entry<Long, List<BigQueryError>> entry : response.getInsertErrors().entrySet()) {
    // inspect row error
  }
}
```

(From the example at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#bigquery-stream-data-java)

Note especially that a failed insert does **not** always throw an exception. You must also check the response object for errors.

> Is it even a good practice to insert into big Query one row at a time every time a user action is initiated ?

Yes, it's pretty typical to stream event streams to BigQuery for analytics. You'll could get better performance if you buffer multiple events into the same streaming insert request to BigQuery, but one row at a time is definitely supported.

Answer (score 1):

A simplified version of Google's example.

```
    Map<String, Object> row1Data = new HashMap<>();
    row1Data.put("booleanField", true);
    row1Data.put("stringField", "myString"); 

    Map<String, Object> row2Data = new HashMap<>();
    row2Data.put("booleanField", false);
    row2Data.put("stringField", "myOtherString"); 

    TableId tableId = TableId.of("myDatasetName", "myTableName");
    InsertAllResponse response =
            bigQuery.insertAll(
                    InsertAllRequest.newBuilder(tableId)
                            .addRow("row1Id", row1Data)
                            .addRow("row2Id", row2Data)
                            .build());

    if (response.hasErrors()) {
        // If any of the insertions failed, this lets you inspect the errors
        for (Map.Entry<Long, List<BigQueryError>> entry : response.getInsertErrors().entrySet()) {
            // inspect row error
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cloud Logging API to write one row at a time.

https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries

Sample code from document
public class QuickstartSample {

/** Expects a new or existing Cloud log name as the first argument. */
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {

```
// Instantiates a client
Logging logging = LoggingOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();

// The name of the log to write to
String logName = args[0]; // "my-log";

// The data to write to the log
String text = "Hello, world!";
LogEntry entry =
    LogEntry.newBuilder(StringPayload.of(text))
        .setSeverity(Severity.ERROR)
        .setLogName(logName)
        .setResource(MonitoredResource.newBuilder("global").build())
        .build();

// Writes the log entry asynchronously
logging.write(Collections.singleton(entry));

System.out.printf("Logged: %s%n", text);
 }
}
```

In this case you need to create sink from dataflow logs. Then message will be redirect to the big Query table.

https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2